# Magento Override Core Block

Tags: php, xml, magento, overriding, block

I'm trying to override class Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation located at app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php

I've created this three files:

1.- app/code/local/Global/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php

2.- app/code/local/Global/Catalog/etc/config.xml

3.- app/etc/modules/Global_All.xml

Code:

Global_All.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Global_Catalog>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Global_Catalog>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Global_Catalog>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </Global_Catalog>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <blocks>
      <catalog>
        <rewrite>
          <navigation>Global_Catalog_Block_Navigation</navigation>
        </rewrite>
      </catalog>
    </blocks>
  </global>
</config>
```

Navigation.php

```
class Global_Catalog_Block_Navigation extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation 
{

   protected function _renderCategoryMenuItemHtml(...){
     .......rewriting code for this method.......

   }

}
```

I've been trying to overwrite this method but I can't, can anybody guide me? maybe check for some typo I haven't noticed yet or Am I missing something?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So the problem was I was trying to overwrite a core file from Magento. When I first asked the question I was CREATING a module, instead of overwriting an existing one. So for you fellows out there if you want to overwride a Magento file the right way, this is how you do it. Very simple.

I was trying to overwrite Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation located at

app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php

All I need it to do, was to create the same root and folders although within the LOCAL folders. Being that said, this would be the route for my overwriting class.

app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php

Note the LOCAL instead of CORE. The Navigation.php is basically the same core file (Copy & Paste), although the function I was trying to overwrite

```
   function protected function _renderCategoryMenuItemHtml(...)
```

within my newley created file, was going to return another statement, different from the core file.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try `<navigation>Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation</navigation>` and rename your Naviation.php to

```
class Global_Catalog_Block_Navigation extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation 
{

   protected function _renderCategoryMenuItemHtml(...){
     .......rewriting code for this method.......

   }

}
```

Finally, change your module.xml to

```
<modules>
    <Mage_Catalog>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Mage_Catalog>
</modules>
```

Comment: But that would be loading the core block, the one I'd like to rewrite. Besides it would be telling Magento to look inside the local folder for an inexistence Mage folder. Am I right?